# Rails+Mongodb get object in json with backslashes from Swift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, mongodb

I'm trying to send a json to Rails+Mongodb from swift.
I have a json with strings, ints and 2 objects inside.
This objects Fabrics and Palettes are embended in WardrobeItem.

From swift I'm sending Fabrics and Palettes right, without the backslashes.

```
         let jsonPalettes = try! JSONEncoder().encode(itemsWardrobe[0].palettes)

         let jsonPString = String(data: jsonPalettes, encoding: .utf8)

         let definitePalettes = jsonPString!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

In Rails console I get
[image]

My params permit are

```
params.require(:wardrobe_items).permit(:name, :body_pos, :pattern, :season, :style, :clo_value, :layer, :last_worn_date, :washing,  :wardrobe_id, :category_id, :events_id => [], :subcategory_ids => [], palettes: [:id, :name_color,  :image_url, :color_palette_square], fabrics: [:id, :name])
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: Identify whether the problem is on the consuming or producing side (i.e. whether the intermediate representation is correct), then update the question to only reference the relevant side.

Comment: I think in swift is right, It's Rails that is getting it in a wrong way

Comment: In that case remove everything swift-related from the question and add actual input to rails app.

Comment: I said "I think", I'm not sure, that's why i put rails swift and mongo